# A property's value is being changed in memory without hitting the setter

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `List<T>` with a type of `Video`. The `Video` class resembles something like this:

```
public class Video {
  public bool IsActive { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  private int videoID;
  public int VideoID {
    get { return videoID; }
    set {
      if (Equals(value, videoID)) return;
      videoID = value;
    }
  }
}
```

I have a complicated scenario that I haven't yet been able to reproduce, so I am not looking for an exact answer, but some theoretical possibilities that will aid me in debugging.

**Scenario**

A view loads which contains a custom `ListBox`. `MeasureOverride()` has been overridden to inspect the values, then it immediately calls `base.MeasureOverride()`. Prior to executing `base.MeasureOverride()`, a Parallel Watch I have set up to inspect the `VideoID` value inside the list, on any one of the items, will be the proper value. Let's say `138`. Stepping-forward once, the value has "magically" changed to something else *consistently*, `158`. A breakpoint at `VideoID.set` is never hit.

In what way is it possible for the value of an object to be manipulated without the debugger hitting the breakpoint? My guess is reflection - which I am using (`fastJSON`) for deserialization.

Thanks for any ideas you may have.

### Edits

(1) the private field `videoID` is only referenced in the `Video` class in the get and set of `VideoID`

(2) Another suspect I have is something in another thread which may be why it seems to happen at a certain *duration* after the view loads, and not necessarily at any consistent point in *code*. `base.MeasureOverride()` is a time-expensive function [for me], alluding to the possibility that I am nowhere near the source of this bug.

(3) I'd also like to add that this issue occurs even when VideoID is an auto-property. So I can't reasonably accept that it has anything to do with the backing field in my example.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a short but complete program?

Comment: `videoID` is a field.  It is conceivable for that field to be modified without going through your setter.

Comment: looks to me like, you have indisposed another old `Video`; so `158` should be the value of `VideoID` with the old `Video` instance.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am currently attempting to do this. There are many pieces to this puzzle, so I'm adding them one at a time.

Comment: @KirkWoll I updated my post. I have 3 total references to the field `videoID`: in the `get`, and twice in the `set` as seen above.

Comment: Is that the whole class?  Is this perhaps a dependency property?  There are cases where when a dependency property is changed, the getter and setter are not called.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway No, the class is not insignificant in size. If I posted it all I think I would have been yelled at for passing the buck.

Comment: multi-threading and deserialization are two candidates

Comment: Is the property in question a dependency property?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway No it is not.  I have almost nailed down the cause, but I don't know how it is doing it. The class which manages this `List<T>` was instantiated through a new `Thread`. This was something I had been experimenting with for other purposes and it slipped my mind. Using `Task`s has removed the symptoms - but I can't posit that it cured anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio, click the cursor on videoID (the backing store lowercase version) and "Find All References". Your sample code does not include videoID's definition, but I suspect it is a `public` rather than `private`... backing stores for properties should normally be `private'.

The find all references should pinpoint locations that could be directly modifying the videoID backing store, bypassing your setter.

Comment: Apologies, it is a private field, I have amended the post.

Comment: Even private, it is modifiable directly by the class that defines it, so the check should be done to see if any direct modifications are made.

Comment: Confirmed that it is not accessed in my code anywhere outside of the `get` and `set`.